# How to download to phone storage?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

am using rn-fetch-blob to fetch an api and download a file directly to my storage, have created a path, I can successfully download it now but when I try to open the file, it shows me: 'cannot open file'

Below is my download function:

```
    download =async (item) => {
    console.log(item)
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
      let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
      RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true,

        addAndroidDownloads : {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            notification : true,
            path: dirs.DownloadDir + "/Baaz_"+Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6) ,
            mime : 'application/mp4',
            mediaScannable : true,
        }
    })
.fetch('GET',  'some url'+item.nameVid,{ 'Cache-Control': 'no-store' }).then((res) => {

  alert('The file has saved!')
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())

})

    }
 }
```

And I have called this function inside a flatlist for my download icons as in below:

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress= {() => this.download(item)}
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="download" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Can anyone please tell me why is it so?
I have already updated the dependencies and added permissions.
Do tell me if you require anything else.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it is somewhat different than android, you will have to use something alongside the [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) library

Once installed, you can use RNFetchBlob like so:

```js
const saveFile = async(uri, headers) => {
  const file = await RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true
  }).fetch('GET', uri, headers);
  const type = 'some/file-type';
  const base64File = await file.readFile('base64');
  const localUrl = `data:${type};base64,${base64File}`;
  await Share.open({
    localUrl
  });
  const filePath = file.path();
  await RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Have updated my code according to android, can download the file, but when I try to open it, it says cannot open file, can you please tell me, why is that so?

Comment: This might be the file format itself not being able to be read with android, what type of file format is it ? @TRINACHAUDHURI I'd suggest to open another question for that though as its unrelated to the download itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039755/file-cannot-open-after-download-on-android  you can check my new question

Answer (score 0):

You Can use **openDocument** and **actionViewIntent** as follow:

```
  RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true, 
    addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        path: 'path',
        mediaScannable: true,
        notification: true,
      },
    path:'path'
    }).fetch('GET', uri, headers)
      .then((resp) => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data);
         }
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(resp.path(), 'application/pdf');;
        }
   }
```